# Using AND in include statement for testng

Tags: java, windows-7, testng, bamboo

I have several tests I am executing in Java.  I want to test with testng.xml.  I have given each test at least two groups.  One from {GRP1, GRP2} and one from {UPDATE, NOUPDATE}.  (Yeah the first group, GRP1 and GRP2 are not the actual names, but I am not sure how much company-sensitive information would be released if I showed their actual names.  The concept remains the same}.

I want to run some of these nightly, but since the ones labeled UPDATE update and create data I do not want these to be running nightly because they will create too much data

I have two tests in the testng.xml:

```html
<test name="TESTGROUP1">
  <groups>
    <run>
      <include name="GRP1"/>
    </run>
  </groups>
    ...
</test>
<test name="TESTGROUP2">
  <groups>
    <run>
      <include name="GRP2"/>
    </run>
  </groups>
    ...
</test>
```

This will run all the GRP1 and GRP2 tests including the UPDATE ones.  I want it to select tests only with both, for instance, GRP1 and NOUPDATE.  I read a comment from a user somewhere to do the following:

```html
    <run>
      <include name="GRP1" />
      <include name = "NOUPDATE" />
    </run>
```

but when I tried this it appeared to be making an OR not an AND condition.  It ran tests with either, not with both.  As a matter of fact I do not (yet) have any tests with the group UPDATE.  (There will be many).  I want to get the testng.xml file correct first.

Does anyone have any suggestions how to do an AND instead of an OR?  The reason I know it was doing OR is that it ran tests satisfying only the GRP1 condition.

I could I guess include just NOUPDATE and not GRP1 and GRP2, but I want the results to be separately listed.

And yes, this will be called nightly from Bamboo.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude a group (see http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#exclusions). e.g.:

```xml
      <run>
        <include name="GRP1" />
        <exclude name="UPDATE" />
      </run>
```

But for the most control you can use BeanShell for [advanced group selection](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#beanshell).

See also [A date in heaven: TestNG and BeanShell « Otaku, Cedric's blog](http://beust.com/weblog/2005/09/30/a-date-in-heaven-testng-and-beanshell/).

Comment: That is what I ended up doing.  It is not quite the same.  In this case it works.